# Implicitly unwrapped optionals

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I'm curious why the implicitly unwrapped optional, **display.text** needs to be unwrapped in the code below.  (From Stanford CS193p)

```
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        if let digit = sender.currentTitle {
            if userIsTypingNumber {
                display.text = display.text! + digit
            } else {
                display.text = digit
            }
        }
}
```

Why is it considered an optional string after the equal sign, but not before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UILabel `display` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, not its property `text`: the property is a normal optional.

So while you don't have to manually unwrap `display`, you have to do it for `display.text`.

Answer (score -1):

Unwrap `optional type` variable is use to get this value content in variable (it can be nil)

Look at define of UILabel:

```
public class UILabel : UIView, NSCoding {

    public var text: String? // default is nil
    ...
}
```

the `text` property is `optional type`. So when get (access) this value you need to unwrap it. In your code you use ! to `force-unwrap` `text` property from `display` label.

And when assign value to an o`ptional typ`e you not unwrap, just assign as normal variable.